# 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history' plus warning using gather with validate_indices

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am fidgeting with some code for physics-informed neural networks.
I am receiving both a warning and an error and I can't come up with what is causing them.

My code is the following:

```
import scipy.optimize
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import time

nu=0.01/np.pi

class uNN:
    #@classmethod
    def build(lb, ub, layers, activation):
        # input layer
        inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(layers[0],))
        #preprocessing layer
        preprocessed = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(scale=2./(ub - lb), offset=-(ub + lb)/(ub - lb))(inputs)
        # hidden layers
        x = preprocessed
        for layer_width in layers[1:-1]:
            x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(layer_width, activation=activation,
                kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(x)
        # output layer
        outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(layers[-1], activation="linear",
            kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(x)
        
        return tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    
class DifferentiationLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, network, **kwargs):
        self.u_network = network
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def call(self, x):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape2:
            tape2.watch(x)
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape1:
                tape1.watch(x)
                u = self.u_network(x)
            u_tx = tape1.batch_jacobian(u, x)
            u_t = u_tx[..., 0]
            u_x = u_tx[..., 1]
        u_xx = tape2.batch_jacobian(u_x, x)[..., 1]
        return u, u_t, u_x, u_xx
    
class PINN:
    def __init__(self, nu, lb, ub, layers=[2, 20, 20, 20, 20, 1], activation="tanh"):
        self.u_NN = uNN.build(lb, ub, layers=layers, activation=activation)
        self.nu = nu
        self.diff = DifferentiationLayer(self.u_NN)
        self.model = self.build_model()
    
    def build_model(self):
        # residual, initial condition and boundary condition points 
        res_pts = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,))
        IC_pts = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,))
        BC_pts = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,))
        
        # stack a differentiation layer to u_NN that computes derivatives
        u, u_t, u_x, u_xx = self.diff(res_pts)

        # residual, initial condition u and boundary condition u
        residual = u_t + u*u_x - self.nu*u_xx
        u_IC = self.u_NN(IC_pts)
        u_BC = self.u_NN(BC_pts)
        
        # build the PINN model
        return tf.keras.models.Model(
            inputs=[res_pts, IC_pts, BC_pts], outputs=[residual, u_IC, u_BC])

    def plot_pinn(self):
        print(type(self.model))
        tf.keras.utils.plot_model(self.model, "my_first_model_with_shape_info.png", show_shapes=True)
        
lb = np.array([0., -1.])
ub = np.array([1., 1.])
    
# build a PINN model
pinn = PINN(nu, lb, ub, layers=[2,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,1])
pinn_model = pinn.model
pinn.plot_pinn()
```

The warning I receive only the first time I run the model is this:

> WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\Gio\anaconda3\envs\tf_nightly_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\parallel_for\pfor.py:2380: calling gather (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) with validate_indices is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
> Instructions for updating:
> The `validate_indices` argument has no effect. Indices are always validated on CPU and never validated on GPU.

And the error is:

> AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'

Any help understanding what is going on would be really appreciated!

Comment: Does [this github thread](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7362) answer your question?

Comment: @gobrewers14 in part yes, thank you. I still get the warning though.

Comment: Its just a warning letting you know an arg to [`tf.gather`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) is being deprecated. It doesn't look like you are calling `tf.gather` directly so it shouldn't impact anything you are doing.

Comment: Why are you define `tf.GradientTape()` inside the layer's call function? `DifferentiationLayer`? Where did you get this approach?

Comment: @M.Innat it's some code I found on github for pinns in tensorflow 2. I liked this idea because I most graphical representation of pinns in papers "stack" a layer containing the differential operators at the end of the network u in order to compute the residue.